# Создаю чистый проект nextjs или react, одна и та же ошибка

Tags: nextjs

```
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - SWC minify release candidate enabled. https://nextjs.link/swcmin
ValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does 
not match the API schema.
 - configuration[0].cache.cacheDirectory: The provided value "C:\\!Portfolio\\main\\.next\\cache\\webpack" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
   -> Base directory for the cache (defaults to node_modules/.cache/webpack).
 - configuration[0].context: The provided value "C:\\!Portfolio\\main" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
   -> The base directory (absolute path!) for resolving the `entry` option. If `output.pathinfo` is set, the included pathinfo is shortened to this directory.
 - configuration[0].module.rules[2].oneOf[4].issuer.and[0].or[0]: The provided value "C:\\!Portfolio\\main" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
 - configuration[0].output.path: The provided value "C:\\!Portfolio\\main\\.next" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
   -> The output directory as **absolute path** (required).
 - configuration[1].cache.cacheDirectory: The provided value "C:\\!Portfolio\\main\\.next\\cache\\webpack" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
   -> Base directory for the cache (defaults to node_modules/.cache/webpack).
 - configuration[1].context: The provided value "C:\\!Portfolio\\main" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
   -> The base directory (absolute path!) for resolving the `entry` option. If `output.pathinfo` is set, the included pathinfo is shortened to this directory.
 - configuration[1].module.rules[2].oneOf[4].issuer.and[0].or[0]: The provided value "C:\\!Portfolio\\main" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
 - configuration[1].output.path: The provided value "C:\\!Portfolio\\main\\.next\\server" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
   -> The output directory as **absolute path** (required).
 - configuration[2].cache.cacheDirectory: The provided value "C:\\!Portfolio\\main\\.next\\cache\\webpack" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
   -> Base directory for the cache (defaults to node_modules/.cache/webpack).
 - configuration[2].context: The provided value "C:\\!Portfolio\\main" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
   -> The base directory (absolute path!) for resolving the `entry` option. If `output.pathinfo` is set, the included pathinfo is shortened to this directory.
 - configuration[2].module.rules[5].oneOf[4].issuer.and[0].or[0]: The provided value "C:\\!Portfolio\\main" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
 - configuration[2].output.path: The provided value "C:\\!Portfolio\\main\\.next\\server" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
   -> The output directory as **absolute path** (required).
    at validate (C:\!Portfolio\main\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\schema-utils3\index.js:1:150815)
    at validateSchema (C:\!Portfolio\main\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:139440:2)
    at create (C:\!Portfolio\main\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:142939:24)
    at webpack (C:\!Portfolio\main\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:142986:32)
    at Object.f [as webpack] (C:\!Portfolio\main\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:97431:16)      
    at HotReloader.start (C:\!Portfolio\main\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\hot-reloader.js:433:45)
    at async DevServer.prepare (C:\!Portfolio\main\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:365:9)     
    at async C:\!Portfolio\main\node_modules\next\dist\cli\next-dev.js:147:9 {
  errors: [
    {
```

Answer (score 1):

C:!Portfolio - проблема в том, что путь, содержит "!".
webpack, angular - многие из них не любят такие пути ;)

о чём собственно и гласит сообщение:
"contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax"